# JavaFX Button invisble, but can be pressed issue

Tags: javafx

EDIT: 
I've determined that the following line is the cause:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
```

Can any explain why it would be causing this issue?

JDK: 13.0.1

FX: 13

Eclipse: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

---

Maybe I'm going crazy, because I feel like I do pretty good with JavaFX... But for some reason, the buttons don't appear, but I can press them, and my logger says the buttons are pressed. I can press the exit button (although invisible), and it quits as expected... so why are the button invisible?

I've attempted to set visibility to true, but that did nothing too. The button sizes appear to be set properly too.

```
public class test extends Application {
    private Button gameButton = new Button("Game");
    private Button mapEditorButton = new Button("Map Editor");
    private Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");

    private static final int buttonHeight = 25;
    private static final int buttonWidth = 100;

    private static final int screenwidth = 350;
    private static final int screenHeight = 150;

    private Scene theScene;
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private VBox root = new VBox(30);
    private HBox top = new HBox(10);

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        primaryStage = stage;

        setButtonSizes();

        root.setPrefSize(screenwidth, screenHeight);
        root.resize(screenwidth, screenHeight);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(top, exitButton);

        top.getChildren().addAll(gameButton, mapEditorButton);
        top.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        theScene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Menu Selector");
        primaryStage.setWidth(screenwidth);
        primaryStage.setHeight(screenHeight);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        primaryStage.setScene(theScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void setButtonSizes() {
        gameButton.setMinSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        gameButton.setMaxSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        gameButton.setPrefSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        mapEditorButton.setMinSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        mapEditorButton.setMaxSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        mapEditorButton.setPrefSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        exitButton.setMinSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        exitButton.setMaxSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        exitButton.setPrefSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    }
}
```

Here's an image of the problem:

[image: Image of Program Running, no buttons showing]

Comment: I can see all three buttons when I run the program. May be a bit more details about the environment can be helpful.

Comment: I'm using JavaFX 13 and JDK 13. Using the setup instructions for eclipse on the official FX website.
I can copy other code I found online, and that seems to work, but this particular code does not, which doesn't make sense.

Also copying this code to another project doesn't work either. I swear this code was working before, and I dont think I made any changes

Comment: Also, using Windows 10 on the latest version of Eclipse, with E(fx)clipse installed.

Comment: I've just updated my question, could you take another look @SaiDandem?

Comment: Good that you provided an [mcve] :) Just a note (unrelated to your problem): please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra From my knowledge (and checking google), my naming conventions are correct. Can you point out what part of the code was not following proper naming conventions?

Comment: Class name `test` should be `Test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After commenting out lines of your code to try to discover what was causing the behavior, I found that it was this line...

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
```

Then I looked at the *javadoc* for class `StageStyle`. It states...

> Specifies the style for this stage. This must be done prior to making the stage visible. The style is one of: `StageStyle.DECORATED`, `StageStyle.UNDECORATED`, `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`, or `StageStyle.UTILITY`

Hmm, `UNIFIED` isn't mentioned there. Nonetheless, your code compiles and runs without error, so `UNIFIED` must be a valid value. So then I looked at the *javadoc* for `UNIFIED` and read this...

> This is a conditional feature, to check if it is supported see `javafx.application.Platform.isSupported`

So running this method...

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.UNIFIED_WINDOW)
```

returned `true` on my Windows 10 64-bit machine running [Oracle] JDK 13.0.1
Despite this, using `StageStyle.UNIFIED` causes a problem. My guess is it may be a bug. In any case, if you remove this line (or comment it out), you will see your buttons.